# How to delete files in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5 and I try to delete a list of files, but files are not deleted, here is my code :

```
public function deleteFiles(){
    $files_names = INPUT::get("files_names");
    Storage::disk('outside')->delete($files_names);
  }
```

And this is my laravel  filesystems:

```
 'outside' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => '/var/pmta/boite/',
     ],
```

I tried also :

```
Storage::delete($files_names);
unlink($files_names)
```

But it does not working either.

Comment: Are there any errors in the log at all? Are the permissions correct on the folder?

Comment: Check here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-how-to-delete-a-file-using-filesystem

Comment: @lan you are right it's a permession issue; after changing `/var/pmta/boite/` to 777 it's working now. thank you